# I need an AS3 function that checks if I'm clicking on Text field

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

My goal is:

- When I click on stage and text field do function.
- but I click on stage without text field do other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe for stage click events, and check, if `target` is your `TextField`:

```
private function setup():void {
    //For testing, some textField
    _textField = new TextField();
    _textField.text = "Some text here";
    _textField.x = _textField.y = 100;
    stage.addChild(_textField);
    //Your Event Listener
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
}

private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (e.target == _textField) {
        trace("Clicked TextField");
    } else {
        trace("Clicked Somewhere");
    }
}
```